# Error: Property 'draggable' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-ui, types

By using Angular 2 and Typescript together with JQuery and JQueryUI I'm getting the following error:

```
Property 'draggable' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'
```

I understand that `.draggable()` is a function that depends on JQueryUI and I've already installed JQuery and JQueryUI in my node_modules using the following commands:

```
npm install --save jquery
npm install --save @types/jquery
npm install --save @types/jqueryui
```

My Webstorm IDE can highlight and lead me to the right location by pressing Ctrl+Click on the function but the console shows the error that I've mentioned above.

I'm importing the module with `import * as $ from 'jquery';` and my code is `$('#element').draggable({containment: '#containment-wrapper});`

Can anyone help me to find where is the error?

## UPDATE

Thanks to @LLai that gave me a good direction on how to solve the issue.
Basically, I have to install the jqueryui core in my project:

```
npm install --save-dev jqueryui
```

Then I have to import `jqueryui` after `jquery` like this:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jqueryui'
```

Well, that gave me a lot of error, but it looks like it's a problem with some version of `@types/jquery`, so I had to follow this [issue](https://github.com/sherweb/ng2-materialize/issues/139#issuecomment-310386058) on Github that recommends installing a specific version of @types/jquery with `npm install @types/jquery@2.0.47 --save-dev`.

After those steps, everything is working fine! Hope it'll help someone else.

Comment: you can use `Renderer2` and get the DOM Element without using `jQuery`

Comment: My question is not how to get the DOM Element but how to get the `.draggable()` function (from JQueryUI) working.

Comment: Besides that I don't know any way to use Renderer2 to get DOM Elements. You can achieve this by using ElementRef instead of Renderer2. Renderer2 can be used to modify or create a new DOM Element. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yup. then why `jQuery` ?

Comment: If you read my question above you'll find out that I'm not looking for a solution on how to get the DOM element. My problem is with the draggable function that is a part of the jQueryUI. That's why I'm using jQuery. `draggable` is not my particular function or a property from my dom element, it's a jQuery function that adds the draggable functionality to any element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to also import `jqueryui` after you import `jquery`

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jqueryui';
```

The draggable() function should be available now.

Comment: You're right! I have to add this import statement also! But that wasn't the only thing I had done. I also installed the jqueryui core with `npm install --save-dev jqueryui` and then I have to install a specific version of @types/jquery according to this conversation on [Github](https://github.com/sherweb/ng2-materialize/issues/139#issuecomment-310386058). Anyway you're right! Thank you very much for your time trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Angular-CLI and get this error even though I have added two lines of 'import ...'. There is a workaround, adding below to the top of your app.module.ts.

```
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts" />
```

I believe this might be some flaws of webpack process inside Angular CLI.